# cordova unable to create date object in ios

Tags: ios, date, object, cordova, nsdate

In `index.js` I have used this code:

```
 alert(new Date("2014-12-31 11:40:00") );
```

But alert shows invalid date in iOS. However it works fine on browser and android.

Comment: Which date it shows then? Generally you would be better off using the other constructors which take the parameters separately like `new Date(2014, 11, 31, 11, 40, 00)`

Comment: I mean alert shows "Invalid Date" . Well in program I have to accept the date and time from the user , then I have to schedule a local notification. So  I'm not sure which date format will be used by the device. So I concatenated the input for date & time and tried to create a date object. It works if I do like this  new Date("2014-12-31") in iOS, but not if I do like this new Date("2014-12-31  11:40:00").

Comment: Any other progess on this? I'm running into it even now. I tried doing it with the "-" in between and it still is throwing me an "invalid date" back.